# Parent() UL of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

HTML:

```
<ul id="column">
<li id="widget8">
    <div class="testhub"></div>
</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
if ($("#widget8").parent("#dock")) {
   $(".testhub").html("<p>dock</p>");
}
else {
    $(".testhub").html("<p>not dock</p>");
}​
```

CSS:

```
#dock {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
#column {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
#widget8 {
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.testhub {
    width 50%;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zVx8s/1/

All i am trying to do is get the **ul** that the **li** is in and if it is on **#dock** then write something to testhub. But doesn't seem to work, check the jsfiddle.

I presume i am using parent incorrectly.

Comment: you cannot set the same id for multiple HTML elements.

Comment: OP please note you got multiple same id's man rest see my Post below with correct demo `:)`

Comment: This was just a mockup in my actual html there is not two id's. the widget8 is dragged and dropped from column to dock. When it is in column i want it to display X and when it is in dock i want it display Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/268mh/

Please note you can never have same id's in DOM. SO I have made `widget8` to class instead!

Rest hope demo helps the cause! `:)`

**code**

```
$(".widget8").each(function() {
    if ($(this).parent().prop("id") == "dock") {
        $(this).find(".testhub").html("<p>dock</p>");

    }
    else {
        $(this).find(".testhub").html("<p>not dock</p>");
    }
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="dock">
<li class="widget8">
    <div class="testhub"></div>
</li>
</ul>

<ul id="column">
<li class="widget8">
    <div class="testhub"></div>
</li>
</ul>
​
```

Comment: there's no reason to comment on every answer telling them something you didn't even realize at first

Comment: Hey man @ianpgall Howz things? chill bruv! Since all answer are from different individuals - just mentioning them before somone go crazy on downvote! did I do something wrong? although note: I did +1 your comment! peace man!

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work the best. I understand i cannot have multiple id's little boo boo on my behalf because i do not have multi ids i was trying to show that the two conditions that this one element (widget8) could be in. As it is a drag and drop box.

Though this works, in my environment it seems to be opposite when it is in the dock it says not dock and when it is not in the dock it says dock. Strange.

Answer (score 2):

The first problem is that on your fiddle you use 2 `ul`s with the same `id`. Use class instead.

You have to loop thrue your `li`s and check parent's length.

```
$(".widget8").each(function) {
    var $element = $(this).parent("#dock");
    if($element.length > 0) {
        var message = 'dock';
    }
    else {
        var message = 'not dock';
    }
    $($element, this).html('<p>' + message + '</p>');
});

​
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zVx8s/3/)

So if you just want to test if has id you just **have to use the right selector**.

```
$('#dock .widget8').html('<p>dock</p>');
```

The selector above get elements which are inside `#dock` and has class `.widget8`.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zVx8s/4/)

Comment: 1st one doesn't write not dock in the element inside column. Also it is writing .html to dock not testhub.

2nd one seems to work fine but not in an if else statement.

Comment: @Keelan First: Probably your `html`is different than that, you can see it working on my demo. Second: I said you can use the second one if you just want to get `li` which's inside `#dock` as you asked. And it works as you can see on my other demo.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `length` to check if it actually exists.

```
if ($("#widget8").parent("#dock").length)
                                 ---^---
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this expression:

```
$("#widget8").parent("#dock")
```

evaluates to a jQuery object, and objects are always "true" values in JavaScript. (*Always*. Even `new Boolean(false)` is a "true" value.)

To see if the above jQuery object contains any actual elements, you can use [the `.length` property](http://api.jquery.com/length/):

```
if ($("#widget8").parent("#dock").length) {
```

(But I agree with jeff that it's more clear to write `parent().is("#dock")`: get the parent, check if it's `#dock`, rather than get the parent-if-it's-`#dock`, see if it exists.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to test the parent `id`, you can use this:

```
if ($("#widget8").parent().is("#dock")) {
    $(".testhub").html("<p>dock</p>");
}
else {
    $(".testhub").html("<p>not dock</p>");
}​
```